# Azure Oracle v12 Instance Auto scaling

Tags: oracle, azure, autoscaling

I am trying to find options of auto scaling available for Oracle v12 instance on Azure.

Is auto scaling in Oracle DB instance, automatically available or can be done only manually or is it is not at all available??
I am trying to google this topic, but not yet found any thing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it look likes there is no automatic auto scaling in Oracle only thing which can be done is to use a VM with good storage and manually mount disks later on based on requirement. It is an assumption I am still looking for a better answer.